# How to organize a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, while-loop

I want to write a code that takes in Input the name and the surname of students, organizing them into a list(with a while-loop).

Then I want to sort this list in alphabetical order, but not according to the name, but according to the surname (consider that the input is Name-Surname)

I began like that:

```
L=[]
i=str(input('Name and surname: (space to stop): '))
L.append(i)
while i!='':
    i=str(input('Name and surname: (space to stop): '))
    L.append(i)
x=L.sort
```

I would like to know if there is any simple way to continue that code, without importing classes

Comment: Hello, do you need to use Python REPL stdin or is your script given a list of names,surnames as a file? If you could ignore the list input problem temporarily in your question, you could focus on dual sorting (sort first by surname, then last name etc)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `key` keyword argument to explicitly state how you want to sort your sequence:

```
names = ['Adam Smith', 'Leia Organa', 'Harry Potter']
sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])
# output: ['Leia Organa', 'Harry Potter', 'Adam Smith']
```

This code assumes that the name and surname are separated by a space.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the name and surname will have a split '-' in between, so we can use the key argument in the builtin function sorted of python.

```
L=[]
i=str(input('Name and surname: (space to stop): '))
L.append(i)
while i!='':
    i=str(input('Name and surname: (space to stop): '))
    L.append(i)
x=sorted(L, key=lambda L: L.split('-')[-1])
```